# err_connection_reset VS2019 (antivirus problem)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, networking

I want to debug my asp.net core applications on localhost with ssl. However if I have kaspersky intalled on my machine when I start debug I obtain err_connection_reset.
I tried:

- Set rule and disable the firewall;
- Disable the traffic analysis;
- Disable the scan for encrypted connections
- Disable everything in Kaspersky

Nothing worked. Can you help me? Thanks

The SSL port is in the right range.
VS2019, IIS10, Kaspersky Internet Security

Answer (score 0):

I tried all things you have mentioned above along with Kaspersky support site, and nothing could fix this issue, except when I hit the "Exit" on Kaspersky.
Unfortunately it took me a lot of time to figure it's an anti-virus issue and took me little time to figure that this is the only available solution for the time being.